# No distance between the nozzle and the print bed level at the center (1) position after bed leveling

Tags: bed-leveling

After I have leveled the print bed on all four corners manually, on moving to the center (1) position I still observe that there is no distance between the print bed and the nozzle. The nozzle literally touches the bed at this position. Furthermore, I am also getting nozzle scrapping on the print surface as the thickness of the printed sample increases (1 mm and above). I am printing 5-152 mm(L)x35 mm(W)x3 mm(T) samples using a commercial PLA filament with a 0.1 mm layer height (30 total layers). The raster width is 0.4 mm while the raster angle in all layers is 0/0°. The bed temperature was 0 °C, while the printing temperature was 220 °C. The printing speed was 60 mm/s. The Z-axis compensation value was 0. The slicer I am using is Ultimaker's Cura, while the printer is Creality's Ender 6. How can I rectify this issue and can anyone guide me as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I would think your bed isn't flat. My magnetic bed has high spots in a couple of places.

Another cause could be that you're just levelling once. Sometimes you need to go around again and check the levelling.

Comment: I have tediously leveled the bed multiple times to ensure the bed level is as uniform as it could be at all four corners, the nozzle still touches the print bed in the center. The printer is new so I am not sure if the bed level could be off so soon (or is it a manufacturing defect?).

Comment: @Beenum: Likely a manufacturing defect. You might be able to correct for it by shimming under the corners or putting something flatter (e.g. a high quality glass bed) between the existing bed and the print surface.

Comment: @Beenum I doubt it's a bed levelling issue, rather an issue with the actual bed itself. Mine had slightly high spots brand new, but not enough to worry me. Put a glass sheet on and see if the problem goes away

Comment: Going on a bit of a tangent, but do you think that Z-offset value should be altered even if no alteration (like adding a glass screen) has been made?

Comment: I think you should just try the simple diagnosis first, grab a bit of glass from a picture frame or small mirror